# Unclear OSX notification banners: where is the cropped text?

Tags: macos, notifications, internationalization

Long **text** notifications banners on MacOS X are cropped. The missing text makes them hard to understand, or even incomprehensible. How can I read the full text of these banners, if nothing shows up in Notification Center?

This is a general issue, and happens with all kinds of notifications on OSX.

The example below appears when trying to call a contact from Contacts.app in Yosemite and *something is not right, which I can not fix, because the message explaining it **is cropped***.

Examples:

[image: German Software Update Notification Banner]

Comment: Click it. idk that app, but most apps come to the front with the notification foremost

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. It is FaceTime, and there is no way to expand the contents of the banner / notification. Hm!

Comment: It doesn't expand, it should bring the specific app to the front

Comment: I do unterstand it does not expand. But what to do, when the app does not show more info, or missing text, and I can only speculate what the text (which exists "somewhere") might say?

Comment: I've no idea in that case - I've never had an app that didn't show me all the relevant info when it came to the front

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the Notification Center by clicking this icon in the top right corner of your menu bar:

[image]

You'll probably see the full text in the "Facetime" section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there is no additional info in the Notification Center.

Comment: Exactly the same text as in the notification popup? If so, I would assume the application in question (Facetime) didn't send any additional text as well.

Comment: There is *no* info regarding the issue in the Notification Center.